# What are the options for CBC solver in Pyomo?

Tags: optimization, pyomo, operations-research, coin-or-cbc

Two questions:

1- Is there any options for cbc solver to stop when a feasible solution is found?
I know there is a opt.options['seconds'] =100 but when I specify small numbers it does not find a feasible one

2- Is there any list for CBC options ? so I can read them all

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To terminate CBC after the first feasible integer solution, set the `maxs` option to 1.

See the CBC [command line documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coin-or/COIN-OR-OptimizationSuite/master/Installer/files/doc/cbcCommandLine.pdf) for a partial list of CBC options.  The [CBC FAQ](https://coin-or.github.io/Cbc/faq.html) in the [CBC Users Guide](https://coin-or.github.io/Cbc/) has instructions for getting a list of all options (including undocumented options) by running CBC in interactive mode from a command prompt, setting the verbosity to level 15, and running the "`?`" command:

```
./bin/cbc
verbose 15
?
```